# Build and Solve for Equation That Has High Degree and Large Coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I am dealing with a problem that need to build and solve 2 equations that has high degree and large coefficient,and I want to find a way to build and solve them in a feasible time, here's the code:

```
ClearAll[equ`vt, equ`vs, ans`vs, ans`vt, r, bar];

n = 15; m = 10; A = 5; L = 5;
pl = 0; pa = 0; pab = 0; ph = 0; pd = 0;
win`h = 0; distr`a = 0;

(* Build Equation for first answer:ans`vt *)
    (* Calculate probability:pl *)
    Do[
    auc = i - 1; lot = n - auc;
    coe = Binomial[n - 1, auc];
    p = coe*v^(lot - 1)*(1 - v)^auc*L/(n - auc);
    pl = pl + p;
    , {i, n - L}]
    Do[
    auc = n - 1 - L + i; lot = n - auc;
    coe = Binomial[n - 1, auc];
    p = coe*v^(lot - 1)*(1 - v)^auc;
    pl = pl + p;
    , {i, L}]

    (* Calculate probability:pa,pab *)
    Do[
    auc = i; lot = n - auc;
    coe = Binomial[n - 1, auc - 1];
    p = coe*v^lot*(1 - v)^(auc - 1);
    pa = pa + p;
    , {i, A}]
    pab = pa;

    Do[
    auc = A + i; lot = n - auc;
    Q = 0;
    Do[
    high = j - 1; low = auc - 1 - high;
    coe = Binomial[auc - 1, high];
    Q = Q + coe*((x - v)/(1 - v))^low*((1 - x)/(1 - v))^high;
    , {j, A}];
    coe = Binomial[n - 1, auc - 1];
    p = coe*v^lot*(1 - v)^(auc - 1);
    pa = pa + p*Q;
    , {i, n - A}]

equ`vt = v*pl - (v - r)*pab == 0 // FullSimplify;
Expand[equ`vt]
(* Solve for ans`vt *)

    (* ans`vt=v/.NSolve[equ`vt && 0<v<1,Reals] *)


(* Build Equation for second answer:ans`vs *)
    (* Calculate price:af *)
    af = {{((Integrate[x*D[pa, x], {x, v, x}])) + (r*pa /. {x -> v})}/
     pa} // FullSimplify;
    af = Flatten[af /. {v -> ans`vt} // FullSimplify];

    (* Calculate probability:ph,pd *)
    Do[
    auc = i; lot = n - auc;
    coe = Binomial[n - 1, auc - 1];
    p = coe*v^lot*(1 - v)^(auc - 1);
    ph = ph + p;
    pd = pd + p;
    , {i, A}]

    Do[
    win`h = 0; distr`a = 0;
    auc = A + i; lot = n - auc;
    Do[
    high = A + j; low = auc - high;
    coe = Binomial[auc - 1, high - 1];
    p = coe*((1 - x)/(1 - v))^(high - 1)*((x - v)/(1 - v))^low;
    win`h = win`h + p*A/high;
    , {j, auc - 1}];
    Do[
    high = j; low = auc - high;
    coe = Binomial[auc - 1, high - 1];
    p = coe*((1 - x)/(1 - v))^(high - 1)*((x - v)/(1 - v))^low;
    distr`a = distr`a + p;
    , {j, A}];
    coe = Binomial[n - 1, auc - 1];
    p = coe*v^lot*(1 - v)^(auc - 1);
    ph = ph + p*(win`h + distr`a);
    pd = pd + p*distr`a;
    , {i, n - A}]

equ`vs = ph*(x - b) - pd*(x - af) == 0 // FullSimplify;
Expand[equ`vs]
(* Solve for ans`vs *)

    (* ans`vs =x/.NSolve[(equ`vs/. {b -> bar}) && 0<=x<=1] *)
```

And here's some basic information and my main concern:

1. n,m,A,L are four parameters representing quantities, they are set to satisfy: n>=m,m=A+L
2. r,bar are two other parameters representing price, they are in [0,1] and set to satisfy:bar>r
3. the solution of first equation is used in the second eqution, and both of them contain high degree and large coefficient, the process of building equation use a lot of "Binomial"
4. ans_vt is a function about r, and ans_vs is a function about r,bar. As r goes up from 0, ans_vt goes up to 1 for max. As bar goes down from 1,first there would be no solution for ans_vs, but it would raise up when bar continues to go down, there is a positive correlation between bar and ans_vs
5. ans_vt and ans_vs should satisfy: ans_vs>=ans_vt in reality, there is an example——n=15,m=10,A=5,L=5,r=0,bar=35/100—— gives two answers: ans_vs=0.672791,ans_vt=0.760844
6. As n,m,A,L goes high,it's hard to solve or even build the eqution,I can't reach the solution using "NSolve" command, and the highest n,m are of 1000000+ level

Are there any other command could help with this problem? Do I have to simplify the equation through math?

Comment: @yarchik Sorry, aren't linear equations means equations with one degree? I think this problem contains two variable and high degree, but it doesn't involve any differentials or integrals. Are there any command that suits this case?

Comment: Yes, you are right about it. But I do not understand something else. You probably search for the unknown `v` as a function of the parameter `r`. I suggest to plot `ContourPlot[-3 v + 1001 v^6 - 6435 v^7 + 19305 v^8 - 35035 v^9 + 
   42042 v^10 - 3003 r v^10 - 31395 v^11 + 10920 r v^11 + 8190 v^12 - 
   15015 r v^12 + 8085 v^13 + 9240 r v^13 - 7755 v^14 - 2145 r v^14 + 
   2002 v^15 == 0, {v, -10, 10}, {r, -10, 10}]`

Comment: @yarchik Thanks for your suggestion. In the whole, I do want to find the unknown v as a function of the parameter r in the first equation. But my problem is now in specific cases or simple cases, I can't even find one unknown v when n,m goes high.

Comment: Unless your equation has some special structure, it is not possible to solve equations of order 5 and higher in simple form [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: @yarchik I am looking for numerical solution, that's why I use NSlolve, maybe that would be possible to solve equation with higher order?